# index.php isn't front page but shows as it is

Tags: homepage

I am working on a website and I am using front-page.php from the 2012 theme as my front page. I set it up that way in settings and set a blank page as the blog in settings. So for the blog, it defaults to index.php which it should and it uses front-page.php as the front-page. My issue is that I have some breadcrumb code set up in the functions.php and there is a conditional in there that says " if not front page, then run code". My problem is that the conditional isn't allowing my code to run on the index page which would be the blog. What am I missing here? did I set it up wrong?

```
function the_breadcrumb() {
   if (!is_home()) {
    echo '<a class="breadcrumb" href="';
    echo get_option('home');
    echo '">';
    bloginfo('name');
    echo "</a> ";
    if (is_category() || is_single()) {
        the_category('title_li=');
        if (is_single()) {
            echo " &rarr; ";
            the_title();
        }
    } elseif (is_page()) {
        echo the_title();
    }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is_home()` and `is_front_page()` can be a bit confusing, they're both true on the same page if your front page is the posts page, but in your case with a static front page, `is_home()` is true on your blog page, and `is_front_page()` is true on your static front page.

From [Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags):

> `is_home()`: When the main blog page is being displayed. This is the page which shows the time based blog content of your site, so if you've set a static Page for the Front Page (see below), then this will only be true on the Page which you set as the "Posts page" in Administration > Settings > Reading.

So if you want your link everywhere but the front page, change it to `if( !is_front_page() )`

Comment: I agree with you that is_home and is_front_page can be confusing. Thank you, that did the trick